# how to enable gui app in github codespaces?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, x11, codespaces

Some opencv code needs to show a GUI window when executing. Instead it shows `Gtk-WARNING **: xxx: cannot open display:`. It happened both on the web and in the desktop app. Is it possible to use something like x11 forwarding to enable this feature? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Goose's answer almost worked for me. I had to use `gh cs ssh -- -XY`.

Answer (score 3):

Use x11 forwarding.

On the codespaces, ssh X11 forwarding is enabled by default.
Just make sure to install `xauth` package, then connect to codespaces use `gh cs ssh -- -X`.